# Powershell RegularExpression not working as expected

Tags: regex, powershell

Hy i just wanted to check if a String contains UpperCase Characters.

So i worte a check for it:

```
$password = "alllowercaseisnotenough"
#check if UpperCase Letter is Contained:
if($password -match '.*[A-Z].*'){
    Write-Host "+ Password has UpperCase Character[s]"
} else {
    Write-Host "- Password has no UpperCase Character[s]"
}
```

The Problem is it says "+ Password has UpperCase Character[s]" can some one Explain why this check isn't working?

Comment: Use `-cmatch`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But WHY the hell Microsoft? Why do they do, such a thing as a non Case Sensitive Regex matcher?

Comment: @maxbit89 Everything string related in PowerShell is case insensitive by default, `'a' -eq 'A'` for example, and reading filenames and paths from disk. It's one of the best features, works brilliantly 90% of the time, trips me up 10% of the time. Case sensitivity works brilliantly never, is tolerable 10% of the time, trips me up 90% of the time. Wouldn't you love to never have to type `grep thing` then retry with `grep -i thing`? PowerShell case-insensitive regexes mean  you can do `gci * | sls thing` and it works usefully instead of pedantically.